# Responsive child div placement

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I am trying to create a big rectangle with some child rectangles slotted inside it in HTML. I thought it would be simple but my CSS is visibly poor :(.

Currently, I am able to create the outer div and the inner divs with fixed positions and that breaks if the screen resizes etc. I want to make it responsive. The fiddle is @ https://jsfiddle.net/q4smybcv/

```css
.outer-div {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 150px;
  width: 30px;
  border: 3px solid grey;
  margin-left: 10px;
  margin-right: 10px;
}

.inner-div {
  position: fixed;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="outer-div">
    <div class="inner-div" id="inner-div-4" style="width: 28px; height: 28px; top: 248px; left: 469px;"></div>
    <div class="inner-div" id="inner-div-3" style="width: 28px; height: 28px; top: 220px; left: 469px;"></div>
    <div class="inner-div" id="inner-div-2" style="width: 28px; height: 28px; top: 192px; left: 469px;"></div>
    <div class="inner-div" id="inner-div-1" style="width: 28px; height: 28px; top: 164px; left: 469px;"></div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Any help is appreciated

Comment: Why are you using `position:fixed`?

Comment: Because otherwise the inner-div-1 comes up on the top of the pile. As I said, it might have to do with my poor css skills and I am trying to understand the whole thing as I go on. Would appreciate any insight as well. Thanks

Comment: Can you use 'px' to '%'  left nad right position  'inner-div'

Comment: @vadivela sorry didnt understand that. Do you want to perhaps update the fiddle or provide any code? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Flexbox can manage all this without positioning at all.

We can add the inner divs *in order* and then switch the order they layout using `flex-direction`. After that it's just a matter of alignment to whichever end you require,

```css
.outer-div {
  display: inline-flex;
  flex-direction: column-reverse;
  height: 150px;
  width: 30px;
  border: 3px solid grey;
  margin-left: 10px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  vertical-align:top;
}


.top {
  justify-content: flex-end;
}

.bottom {
  justify-content: flex-start;
}
.inner-div {
  border: 1px solid blue;
  width: 28px;
  height: 28px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.blue {
background:lightblue;
color:white;
}

.push {
margin-top:auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer-div top">
  <div class="inner-div blue">1</div>
  <div class="inner-div">2</div>
  <div class="inner-div">3</div>
  <div class="inner-div">4</div>
</div>

<div class="outer-div top">
  <div class="inner-div blue push">1</div>
  <div class="inner-div">2</div>
  <div class="inner-div">3</div>
  <div class="inner-div">4</div>
</div>

<div class="outer-div bottom">
  <div class="inner-div blue">1</div>
  <div class="inner-div">2</div>
  <div class="inner-div">3</div>
  <div class="inner-div">4</div>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks a lot. this is almost there. is there any way to make the div 1 go to the bottom of the parent div?

Comment: all of them from bottom up

Comment: Sure...see revised answer

Answer (score 1):

I really really recomend you read this: [Grid-Layout-Tutorial with examples](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/)
It wont take you more than 20 minutes to find what you need

Here a lil snipped of my current Project:

```
.upper-grid-container {
        display: grid;  // most important
        grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);  //it sooo easy to tell how many columns you want
        grid-template-rows: auto;
        grid-column-gap: 0.1rem;
        grid-row-gap: auto;

      }
```

That way I was able to create this very dynamic layout

[image: divs in a grid]

Answer (score -1):

You can do it using flex very easily. Also, you can use grid as well.

```css
.outer-div {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  height: 150px;
  width: 80%;
  border: 3px solid grey;
  margin-left: 10px;
  margin-right: 10px;
}

.inner-div {
  min-width: 50px;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  margin: 20px;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="outer-div">
    <div class="inner-div" id="inner-div-4" style="width: 28px; height: 28px; top: 248px; left: 469px;"></div>
    <div class="inner-div" id="inner-div-3" style="width: 28px; height: 28px; top: 220px; left: 469px;"></div>
    <div class="inner-div" id="inner-div-2" style="width: 28px; height: 28px; top: 192px; left: 469px;"></div>
    <div class="inner-div" id="inner-div-1" style="width: 28px; height: 28px; top: 164px; left: 469px;"></div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

Fixed position puts your content relative to the viewport. However the problem is you inline sytles. You'r top: and left: properties. Because you need a REALTIVE positioned element to wich those divs can refer.

```
.container {
      position: relative;
    }
    .outer-div {
      display: inline-block;
      position: absolute;

      height: 150px;
      width: 30px;
      border: 3px solid grey;
      margin-left: 10px;
      margin-right: 10px;
    }

    .inner-div {
      border: 1px solid blue;
      width: 28px; 
      height: 28px
    }


<html>

<head>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="outer-div">
        <div class="inner-div" id="inner-div-4"></div>
        <div class="inner-div" id="inner-div-3"></div>
        <div class="inner-div" id="inner-div-2"></div>
        <div class="inner-div" id="inner-div-1"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```